# Как сравнить 2 стека

Tags: delphi, стек

Из двух стеков с целыми числами создать новый стек из элементов первого стека, которых нет во втором стеке.

С массивами я могу такое сделать, а вот со стеками не знаю как
Есть идея фиксировать вначале первый элемент первого стека и сравнивать его со всеми элементами второго стека, если они равны то запихивать его в 3-й стек, потом фиксировать второй элемент и всё по новой 
но как это в синтаксисе будет выглядеть я не знаю, гугл особо ничего не дал по сравнению элеметов

Comment: Господи, какие идиоты придумывают такие задачи? Они вообще в курсе, зачем нужны стеки?

Comment: а ты это нашёй лекторше скажи, вот так вот сейчас программистов учат(топовый вуз)

Comment: @fori1ton: Рискну предположить, что нет :-) Ну или специальная идиотская учебная задача для того, чтобы помучиться и собственной шкуре понять, что стек для таких операций слабо приспособлен.

Comment: ну возможно вы правы

Comment: А вы и правда спросите лекторшу, нафига такая задача. Для теоретико-множественных операций наподобие дополнения надо пользоваться, понятно, множеством.

Comment: очень нужен код к этой задаче!
точнее, к той части, где элементы сравниваются и заполняется третий стек.
если такой код имеется, очень прошу скинуть

Comment: @maxkosh: лабораторная работа не получается? ;-)

Comment: @VladD принцип понимаю, но не могу это в виде кода представить

Comment: @maxkosh: а что именно не выходит? Если вы зададите отдельный вопрос и покажете свой код, думаю, вы получите больше ответов. (Открою вам секрет: вопросы типа «напишите за меня код» тут не приветствуются, а вот «я написал вот такое, и получается X, а хотелось бы Y» идут гораздо лучше.)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

1. разберите второй стек, и все элементы запихните во множество
2. разбирайте первый стек; если текущий элемент есть во множестве, не добавляйте его в результирующий стек, иначе добавляйте

Comment: П.2 -- если это нормальный стек, то надо потом ещё реверс сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритм такой (лекторша не сможет придраться):

1. Если второй стек не пуст, переливаем элементы из первого стека в третий, ищем top из второго стека.
2. Если не нашли, выталкиваем из второго, заносим в четвертый стек (результирующий)
3. Если второй стек не пуст, переливаем из третьего стека в первый, ищем top из второго стека.
4. Если не нашли, выталкиваем из второго, заносим в четвертый стек (результирующий)
5. идем в п.1.

Для понимания принципа стека нормальная задача. С точки зрения практической ценности интереса не представляет. Другие варианты лабы могут быть с очередями и деками.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov: Вы правы, множество не поможет, если надо сохранить повторы. Хотя можно использовать его частично: второй стек заменить на множество (ну или перелить в множество), теперь проверка элемента первого стека на пригодность можно сделать быстрой.

В любом случае, задача на теоретико-множественные операции, и, как вы совершенно правильно отметили, практической ценности не представляет.